# LOAD DATA INFILE error in MySQL

Tags: sql-server, import

I try to import csv data into mySQL (microsoft slq server 2014 on windows 7). I use the following code

```
USE [DataAnalytics]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[npi_yy]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[npi_yy](

[NPI] [NUMERIC] (10) NULL,
[Entity Type Code] [NUMERIC] (1) NULL,
[Replacement NPI] [NUMERIC] (10) NULL,
[Employer Identification Number (EIN)] [VARCHAR] (9) NULL,
[Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)] [VARCHAR] (70) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

LOAD DATA INFILE 

    'c:\data\npidata_20050523-20160612_sample2.csv'

INTO TABLE [dbo].[npi_yy]

  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'

  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

And got an error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 354
Incorrect syntax near 'INFILE'.
```

I checked that `CREATE TABLE` worked by looking at the empty table.
and checked `c:\data\npidata_20050523-20160612_sample2.csv` exists by opening it by putting the filename in explore

Head of the csv:

```
"NPI","Entity Type Code","Replacement NPI","Employer Identification Number (EIN)","Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)"
"1588667638","1","","",""
"1497758544","2","","<UNAVAIL>","CUMBERLAND COUNTY HOSPITAL SYSTEM
"1306849450","1","","",""
"1215930367","1","","",""
"1023011178","2","","<UNAVAIL>","NAPA VALLEY HOSPICE & ADULT DAY SERVICES"
```

Anybody know what was wrong? Any help's appreciated.

Comment: Do you really think someone is going to download a 5GB file?  Include a small sample, or kill the link.

Comment: Are you certain that the file exists and is reachable from your script?  Perhaps you should be using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` ?

Comment: thanks@TimBiegeleisen. add LOCAL and it reports `Incorrect syntax near 'LOCAL'.`....

Comment: Did your table get created? Perhaps the CREATE TABLE command is not constructed properly - and the error is extending into next command. Can you run the Load Data command in separate script?

Comment: Post your full  'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[npi_yy]` code and use pastebin or code tags here to show a subset of your csv file

Comment: Also show the full filename instead of `'C:\...\npidata_20050523-20160612.csv'` - I assume that's your shorthand version - doesn't make any sense why you'd shorten it for us if you want us to look at all possibilities

Comment: There is no problem with the file. The command is incorrect. What database software do you use? The posted code is not MySQL (except for the `LOAD DATA` statement).

Comment: @axiac i copied the code from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html. I'm using microsoft sql server 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except of the `LOAD DATA` statement, the code you posted is for [Microsoft SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198336.aspx). `LOAD DATA` is a statement specific to [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/). They are two unrelated database software, with different syntax rules and they extended the SQL standard in different ways. They cannot be mixed.

The `LOAD DATA` statement is an extension of the standard provided by MySQL. Microsoft SQL Server provides the [`BULK INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement for this purpose.

Your code should be something like:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[npi_yy]
FROM 'c:\data\npidata_20050523-20160612_sample2.csv'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
GO
```

Read more about the [`BULK INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement.